# Client-side extensions in Windows: How to apply it to the local group policy?

Tags: c++, windows, group-policy

I was looking for a way to implement CSE that will be registered on a local machine. I want ProcessGroupPolicy function of this CSE to be ran on every local user log-in.

What I've done so far:

I have implemented the function [CSEProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nc-userenv-pfnprocessgrouppolicy) - I am not showing implementation details here, but can post them if necessary

```
DWORD CSEProcess(_In_ DWORD dwFlags, _In_ HANDLE hToken, _In_ HKEY hKeyRoot, _In_ PGROUP_POLICY_OBJECT pDeletedGPOList, _In_ PGROUP_POLICY_OBJECT pChangedGPOList, _In_ ASYNCCOMPLETIONHANDLE pHandle, _In_ BOOL* pbAbort, _In_ PFNSTATUSMESSAGECALLBACK pStatusCallback);
```

exported it in dll, registered CSE as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/policy/registering-a-policy-callback-function)

```
result = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &regKey, NULL);
```

My question is - why is this not applying on user login?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/policy/initial-processing-of-group-policy) correctly, this should happen anyway.

Specifically (emphasis mine):

> For computers, Group Policy is applied when the computer starts. **For users, Group Policy is applied at log on**.

So what am I missing in that paragraph which is troubling you? It certainly wouldn't make sense to change a policy setting that pertains to the entire machine each time a user logs on.

Comment: I believed that I have implemented everything as per documentation (even checked the reg keys manually to make sure everything looks good). 
The  CSEProcess function never gets called. I am trying to figure out what I've missed? Do I need to edit local gpt.ini somehow to trigger this?

Comment: Sorry, you've reached the extent of my knowledge.  How are you debugging this?

Comment: I actually managed to put wrong Dll path (typo). Took me a day to notice that i had triple l in dll. Sorry for the question and thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks for 'fessing up :)